# Setting uniforms in webgl

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Can anyone explain or point me in the right direction of a good explaination of the different functions used to set uniform values. In the cheat sheet [here](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf) we get this:

`void uniform[1234][fi](uint location, ...)
void uniform[1234][fi]v(uint location, Array value)
void uniformMatrix[234]fv(uint location, bool transpose, Array)`

but i'd like to know what each of these is doing and what the f's and i's are for.

Comment: Of course. As a lowly javascript developer floats and integers aren't at the forefront of my mind. I would guess that the v is referring to vectors then, but why would there be a v on the uniformMatrix and why would you be able to create a uniform1fv with only one dimension. Wouldn't that be the same as uniform1f?

Comment: I've merged my comments into an answer

Comment: Is this helpful? http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`1234` = dimensions

`f` = float

`i` = integer

`v` The final character, if present, is v,
indicating that the command takes an array (a vector) of values rather
than a series of individual arguments

For a non array uniform the only difference between `v` and `non v` versions of the uniform functions is just how you provide the data to it:

`uniform1fv(loc,[3.14159])` vs `uniform1f(loc,3.14159)`.

`uniform3fv(loc,[.5,1.,.5])` vs `uniform3f(loc,.5,1.,.5)`

but for an array uniform you can set the entire array using the `v` functions

in shader

```
uniform float someArray[10];
```

in js

```
// at init time
var location = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray");

// at render time
var arrayWith10Values = [5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 12, 0.1, 2, -1];
gl.uniform1fv(location, arrayWith10Values);
```

To do that with the non `v` functions you'd have to look up every location

```
var location0 = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray[0]");
var location1 = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray[1]");
var location2 = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray[2]");
var location3 = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray[3]");
var location4 = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "someArray[4]");
...etc...

gl.uniform1f(location0, value0);
gl.uniform1f(location1, value1);
gl.uniform1f(location2, value2);
gl.uniform1f(location3, value3);
gl.uniform1f(location4, value4);
...etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the line
 "To do that with the non v functions you'd have to look up every location"

Answer (score 5):

The values within the square brackets refer to the dimension and the datatype of your variable. So you have the following list

- 1 - one value
- 2 - two values
- 3 - three values
- 4 - four values
- f - your data is a float
- i - your data is an integer
- v - your data refers to an array

In the WebGL Specification are more infromation about that.

Comment: I downvoted. Please consider removing the `This is not very hard to understand` statement.